# Vision API : Difference in results from drag drop and java vision api client

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have the attached image as shown in the bottom of this question.

I go to drag and drop: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop

Upload this image on above link and go to Web. I see 50 links under "Pages with Matched Images"

Now I run the vision API client in Java

```
            for (WebPage page : annotation.getPagesWithMatchingImagesList()) {
                String url = page.getUrl();
                System.out.println(url);
            }
```

The result of above code is only 10 links.

```
http://www.clubic.com/connexion-internet/fai-sfr-box-neufbox/actualite-755413-probleme-technique-sfr-pu-prevenir.html
https://www.nextinpact.com/news/93154-option-tv-obligatoire-l-information-clients-sfr-a-souffert-d-un-probleme-technique.htm
https://www.macg.co/ailleurs/2015/02/sfr-facture-son-option-tv-obligatoire-sans-prevenir-87427
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cat.gencat.mobi.vacunes&hl=en
http://pressmans.com/index.php/probleme-sfr-tv-ugg01
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moddity.marketing4ecommerce&hl=en
https://support.shopo.in/hc/en-us/articles/209451025-How-to-get-orders-
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.kontinent.protection&hl=en
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appinventor.ai_fendy3d.Phone_Jammer&hl=en
http://www.media.mts.ru/technologies/124104/
```

Why is this mismatch. Is it normal or am I missing something.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how exactly looks your http request.
But make sure you read the API docs for that maxResults parameter. This can be the cause for so few results.